# Codeigniter 4 - setting app.baseURL in .env file & controller sub-directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, base-url, codeigniter-4

I have following **Codeigniter 4** project structure. I am having problem with using base_url() and setting app.baseURL in .env file properly. Following two questions are due to this same problem:

**Project Structure**

```
wamp-web-root
    ci_4_project
        public
        app
        assets
```

**APP Structure**

```
public
system
app
    Controllers
        First_controller.php
        Subfolder1
            Subfolder2
                Subfolder3
                    Second_controller.php
```

> **FIRST QUESTION - controller sub-directories**

My **First_controller.php** 
`<a href="<?php echo base_url()."/public/first_controller";?>">Link</a>"` works fine but my **Second_controller.php** `<a href="<?php echo base_url()."/public/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/second_controller";?>">Link</a>"` is not working.

> **SECOND QUESTION - accessing assets folder**

I use following code to include css files in my views:
`<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/bootstrap-4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`

In my **.env file**: if I use `app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/ci_4_project/public/'` then **Codeigniter Debug Toolbar** is displayed but css files are not included in views.
If I use `app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/ci_4_project/'` i.e. without appending **public** then css files are included in views but **Codeigniter Debug Toolbar** is not displayed. Apparently this is because assets folder is not inside public folder but instead at same level so when I use public in baseURL, assets are not included. My question is: how to define app.baseURL and whether to add **public** or not in the url.

Comment: Why are you wanting to access controllers so many levels deep from the URL?

Answer (score 0):

For your second controller, make sure you correctly namespaced it:

```
 namespace App\Controllers\Subfolder1\Subfolder2\Subfolder3;
```